# rake db:create ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When i am running rake db:migrate i am getting the following error . Please let me know the reason.

Environment  - Windows 7 Home Premium 
Rails

```
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
F:/example/ROR//vendor/plugins/savage-beast/lib/tasks/savage_beast.rake:2
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:13
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:13:in `each'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:13
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
F:/example/ROR/Rakefile:10
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
F:/ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
F:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19:in `load'
F:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting? That's just the stack dump.

Comment: how to get the exact error that is the exact thing what i have seen in the console

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Rails gem is not installed properly because Rake:db create is a Rails method and it seems in your case that it is not running properly.

You can refer [this](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/150857)

[Step By Step](http://allaboutruby.wordpress.com/2006/01/09/installing-rails-on-windows-step-by-step-tutorial/) Installer

Comment: I installed it properly as i am able to run other apps correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following command `rake db:create:all` followed by `rake db:migrate` You coudl get this error if you have no databses setup for your project. And do you have a `database.yml` file in your app/config folder?